# How to view records that fall between 2 date range in sharepoint?

Tags: view, data

How to view records that fall between 2 date range in sharepoint?

Eg - How to view the list of records who are on vacation today from date range fields "Vacation start date" and "Vacation end date".

If vacation start date is 1/1 and end date is 1/5. I should view this person in my today's vacation list view. (Considering today's date is 1/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for this scenario on a list view, it can be simply done through list view filter.

Modify the view (relevant) -> Go to Filter section -> Apply the filter accordingly.
In your scenario create a filter with below condition.

```
Start Date >= [Today] AND End Date <= [Today]
```

Comment: It works but it picks up only todays date. The result not showing up for date range. Eg it shows vacation list of resources who took off only 1 day (ie today), but it misses the resources who took off 3 days including today.

Comment: It works - Sorry I made small mistake.